# How to specify y values in histogram?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to write a program that takes in two arrays, one for y values and the other one for the bins, and generate a histogram that put the y values into the corresponding bins' range. 
e.g. y = 0.5 when 0 < x< 0.1, y = 0.2 when 0.1 < x <0.2

I cloudn't find any ways to sepcify the y-values in histogram with matplotlib, or is it possible to do so ?

Ps. Can I use bar chart to do so ? but I didn't find a way to specify bins in bar chart , Thanks!

Comment: The question is not really clear. A histogram aggregates some data, you hence do not specify any `y` value at all; instead `y` is the result of some binning. If on the other hand you already have some `y` value for a certain `x`, then you just need to plot `y` against `x` (e.g. as a bar plot). However in the latter case, it would be unclear what a "bin" would refer to, because each `x` value has its `y` conterpart. I guess it would help if you showed some example of data in use and explained the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a [bar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) plot, where you can specify the x values and "height". For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array([4,5,6])

plt.bar(a,b)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For example, you can fill the arrays with an `if` condition:

```
a=np.array([0.01,0.15,0.18,0.05,0.15])
b=np.zeros(len(a))

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > 0. and a[i] < 0.1:
        b[i] = 0.5
    elif a[i] > 0.1 and a[i] < 0.2:
        b[i] = 0.2
```

Comment: Hi, one more question, how to achieve the same functionality like the bin in histogram using bar?

Comment: what functionality?